# Finding the first occurrence of an element in a SQL database

Tags: sql

I have a table with a column for customer names, a column for purchase amount, and a column for the date of the purchase. Is there an easy way I can find how much first time customers spent on each day?

So I have

```
Name    |     Purchase Amount | Date
Joe           10                9/1/2014
Tom           27                9/1/2014
Dave          36                9/1/2014
Tom           7                 9/2/2014
Diane         10                9/3/2014
Larry         12                9/3/2014
Dave          14                9/5/2014
Jerry         16                9/6/2014
```

And I would like something like

```
Date     |     Total first Time Purchase
9/1/2014       73
9/3/2014       22
9/6/2014       16
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is standard SQL and works on nearly all DBMS

```
select date, 
       sum(purchaseamount) as total_first_time_purchase
from (
   select date,
          purchaseamount, 
          row_number() over (partition by name order by date) as rn
   from the_table
) t    
where rn = 1
group by date;
```

The derived table (the inner select) selects all "first time" purchases and the outside the aggregates based on the date.

Comment: I think you are missing , Group By date

Answer (score 1):

The two key concepts here are `aggregates` and `sub-queries`, and the details of which dbms you're using may change the exact implementation, but the basic concept is the same.

1. For each name, determine they're first date
2. Using the results of 1, find each person's first day purchase amount
3. Using the results of 2, sum the amounts for each date

In SQL Server, it could look like this:

```
select Date, [totalFirstTimePurchases] = sum(PurchaseAmount)
from (
    select t.Date, t.PurchaseAmount, t.Name
    from table1 t
      join (
        select Name, [firstDate] = min(Date)
        from table1
        group by Name
        ) f on t.Name=f.Name and t.Date=f.firstDate
    ) ftp
group by Date
```

Comment: `row_number` is *very* useful, but this format should work on virtually any DBMS

Comment: @PhilipKelley: the above will only work on SQL Server that's true.  But only because of the non-standard column alias quoted identifiers - not because of the window functions. Window functions are supported by "virtually every DBMS".

Comment: Every recent DBMS, yes... but SO gets occasional posts from users of older systems (SQL 2000, for example), and these users are a tad more likely to not specify what software version they are using, resulting in comments like "doesn't work on my system". As such, I tend to err on the side of caution when versions are not specified. (You are also correct re: column aliases--I was focusing more on the nested subqueries.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server you can accomplish this with either `sub-queries` or CTEs ([Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)). Since there is already an answer with `sub-queries`, here is the CTE version.

First the following will identify each row where there is a first time purchase and then get the sum of those values grouped by date:

```
   ;WITH cte
    AS (
        SELECT [Name]
            ,PurchaseAmount
            ,[date]
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [date] --start at 1 for each name at the earliest date and count up, reset every time the name changes
                ) AS rn
        FROM yourTableName
        )
    SELECT [date]
        ,sum(PurchaseAmount) AS TotalFirstTimePurchases
    FROM cte
    WHERE rn = 1
    GROUP BY [date]
```

Comment: CTEs are nothing special to SQL Server (in fact SQL Server was pretty late "to the game")

Comment: Perhaps, but this row_number syntax is different in many DBMS I believe

Comment: Nearly all those DBMS that support window functions actually stick to the SQL standard (not all support all options, but the syntax is always the same)